# Separating one column to multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to retrieve data from our DB and there is another table that I joined where I need to get the data from that column but separated into multiple columns.

I have this code so far:

```
SELECT 
    restaurants.name AS 'Name',
    extras_time_slots.restaurant_id AS 'DC ID',
    SUM(capacity) AS 'Seats opened', 
    meal_group_name AS 'Category',
    CASE
        WHEN extras_events.status = 0 THEN 'Offline'
        WHEN extras_events.status = 1 THEN 'Submitted'
        WHEN extras_events.status = 2 THEN 'Online'
        ELSE 'Unknown'
    END AS 'Status',
    CASE
        WHEN restaurants.region_id = 29 THEN 'Beijing'
        WHEN restaurants.region_id = 31 THEN 'Shanghai'
        WHEN restaurants.region_id = 63 THEN 'Guangzhou'
        WHEN restaurants.region_id = 83 THEN 'Shenzhen'
        WHEN restaurants.region_id = 86 THEN 'Hangzhou'
        WHEN restaurants.region_id = 88 THEN 'Suzhou'
        WHEN restaurants.region_id = 91 THEN 'Chengdu'
        ELSE 'Unknown'
        END AS 'City',
    (
        SELECT extras_event_meals.price
        FROM extras_event_meals
        WHERE meal_type LIKE 'lunch'
        AND extras_events_id 
    ) AS 'Lunch price',
    (
        SELECT extras_event_meals.price
        FROM extras_event_meals
        WHERE meal_type LIKE 'dinner'
        AND extras_events_id 
    ) AS 'Dinner price',
    (
        SELECT extras_event_meals.price
        FROM extras_event_meals
        WHERE meal_type LIKE 'brunch'
        AND extras_events_id 
    ) AS 'Brunch price'
FROM extras_time_slots
JOIN restaurants
    ON extras_time_slots.restaurant_id = restaurants.id
JOIN extras_events
    ON extras_events.restaurant_id = restaurants.id AND extras_events.project = extras_time_slots.project
JOIN extras_event_meals
    ON extras_event_meals.extras_event_id = extras_events.id
WHERE extras_time_slots.project = 'rwcn_autumn_2018'
GROUP BY restaurants.id;
```

So the table extras_events_meal_price has for one restaurant multiple "meals" which have a type and price.

Here are the columns:

```
id
extras_events_id
meal_type
price
created_at
updated_at
```

One restaurant can have multiple meal_type and price, but they are in the same column, so with my last SELECT subquery I'm trying to split them in 3 columns: brunch price, lunch price, dinner price.

The error I get all the time is:

> Subquery returns more than 1 row.

Comment: Also if I don't explain this clearly feel free to ask for clarification, or if I ask the question the wrong way feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never finished your query in your subselect statements. `extras_events_id` should equal `extras_events.id`. By not including it, you're simply just checking if it's `true`, which would return every `meal_type` of 'lunch' in the table:

```
SELECT extras_event_meals.price
FROM extras_event_meals
WHERE meal_type LIKE 'lunch'
AND extras_event_id = extras_events.id
```

Comment: Why should extras_events_id equal restaurants.id? I don't think they are the same number at all

Comment: I can see that the AND statement is not finished, I get that part. So that's one thing wrong. But I'm not clear about extras_events_id should equal restaurants.id

Comment: How are the two tables linked? `extras_events_id` should equal something in the restaurants table, correct? Maybe it's `extras_events_id = extras_event_meals.id`? I'm a bit confused at the actual connections between the tables (What in restaurants should link to what in extras_event_meals), fix that (In all 3 subqueries) and you should be golden.

Comment: So, if I understand my tables correctly, this is how this is all linked:

restaurants: contains restaurants information.

extras_events: contains id and then restaurant_id and then project. It's a many to many relationship: one restaurant can have multiple projects and projects can have multiple restaurants.
extras_events link to restaurants through restaurant_id

extras_events_meals: contains an id and then restaurant_id and then project. One restaurant can have multiple meals per project.
extras_events_meals link to extras_events through extras_event_id

Comment: See my updated answer. Try that, and let me know if you're still having issues.

Comment: Done! I think 

Comment: Actually do you have a resource online I could read that has the explanation for this specific issue? I'd like to understand what was wrong or why I couldn't get it.

Comment: When you run a `SELECT` statement as an alias for a column, it requires that the associated table have exactly 1 or 0 rows, otherwise it doesn't know what data to actually fill into the column. Your query, (Grabbing the data from the other table), was not filtering down to a specific event, it was just grabbing all meals `WHERE meal_type LIKE 'lunch'`, and it didn't know what actual price to put into that field. This is why you got the error.